# Setting CORs Headers For Socket.IO

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, cors, apache2

I am trying to use a socket.io service via an Apache proxy however I keep getting this error:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:18996' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Here is my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.com

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, cl$

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/api
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/MYSSL
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/MYSSL
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    <Location /api1>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8005
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8005
    </Location>
    <Location /api2>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000
    </Location>
    <Location /socketioservice>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9090
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9090
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my Node JS code:

```
const express    = require('express'),
      app        = express(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      server     = require('http').createServer(app),
      io         = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

io.on('connection', user => {
    //Socket.io Functions
});

server.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server Running'));
```

I have other NodeJS services running on the same box as you can see and those are just Express JS Apis and they work perfectly (using the same cors configuration you see in the socket.io code).

I have tried to alter the cors settings like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    next();
});

const server = app.listen(cross.NormalizePort(process.env.PORT || 9090));
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
    log: false,
    agent: false,
    origins: '*:*',
    transports: ['websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']
});
```

But that gives me the exact same result. I have tried to use it without cors entirely and I get the same error.

I am using it from an AngularJS app with a factory like so:

```
.factory('Links', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    let socket = io.connect('https://myurl/socketioservice', { secure: true });
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

I have verified that the socket.io service does work by running it locally I am able to connect to it just fine using `http://localhost:8000`. When I deploy it to the production box I am able to use it like so: `http://prodipaddress:8000` and that works as well.

However, I need it to be able to run through the Apache proxy because otherwise it won't be accessible from outside my network due to firewall rules.

How can I configure cors to allow me to connect to my socket.io service?

Answer (score 1):

You're using credential mode (means you're sending some authentication cookie from your angular app) and as for CORS specification you cannot use the wildcard * in this mode.

you should change your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to match the specific host who generated the request

you can change this line:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

to

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:18996');
```

but to be more generic:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin') 
|| req.header('x-forwarded-host') || req.header('referer') || req.header('host'));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, however I am still getting the same error, now with this added 
`GET https://myurl/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M0DfApj 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: what error are you getting now on the client related to the CORS headers?

Comment: The exact same one as in my post.

Comment: if apache always sets the same header it should override the one on nodejs. try to remove from apache config the rule: Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: Now I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:17885' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Comment: you need to take care that you're setting the headers twice, in your nodejs server and in your apache config, probably apache is overriding what you did on node. you have to end up with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin equal to 'http://localhost:17885'